# Error during expansion of macro in Chicken Scheme

Tags: macros, lisp, scheme, chicken-scheme, define-syntax

I'm learning how the macro system in Scheme works and I'm trying to make my code look more JavaScript-y. So I thought I would start with the `function` macro. This is how I want a function definition to look:

```
(function id (x) x)
```

It should expand to the following:

```
(define (id x) x)
```

So I write a macro as follows:

```
(define-syntax function
    (lambda (name args . body)
        `(define (,name ,@args) ,@body)))
```

However when I use it I get the following error (in Chicken Scheme):

```
Error: during expansion of (define ...) - in `define' - lambda-list expected: (define ((function id (x) x) . #<procedure (rename sym1348)>) #<procedure (compare s11400 s21401)>)

    Call history:

    <syntax>      (function id (x) x)
    <eval>    (##sys#cons (##core#quote define) (##sys#cons (##sys#cons name args) body))
    <eval>    (##sys#cons (##sys#cons name args) body)
    <eval>    (##sys#cons name args)    <--
```

Where am I going wrong? In addition how do I read such error messages to be able to debug the program myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Scheme, using syntax-rules():

```
(define-syntax function
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((function name (args ...) body ...)
     (define (name args ...) body ...))))
```

The error you are seeing is that apparently Chicken Scheme's compiler expects the second form of `define-syntax` to be a macro expansion procedure - they typically require arguments for renaming and comparing identifiers.  The `lambda` in your macro doesn't produce a suitable function - `syntax-rules` does.

The above is guaranteed hygienic.

Answer (score 2):

The way you have defined the macro is not correct as per Chicken documentation. Your code seems to be more inspired by Common Lisp macros. Check out the doc [here](http://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/Macros) for `define-syntax` with transformer function:

The macro should be defined as:

```
(define-syntax function
    (lambda (expr inject compare)
        `(define (,(cadr expr) ,@(caddr expr)) ,(cadddr expr))))
```

expr is the whole macro expression i.e `(function id (x) x)` and inject and compare are special utility functions passed to the macro while perfoming macro expand.

Comment: This is missing the `ir-macro-transformer` call, so it won't work out of the box. In older versions of CHICKEN it might've worked but it also is misleading because the default syntax transformer would be an `er-macro-transformer`, which doesn't take "inject" but "rename".