# Cleanest way to make a "derived" identifier?

Tags: syntax, macros, scheme, chez-scheme

It's very common for Scheme macros to make "derived" identifiers, like how defining a record type `foo` (using the R6RS syntactic record API) will by default define a constructor called `make-foo`. I wanted to do something similar in my own macro, but I couldn't find any clean way within the standard libraries. I ended up writing this:

```
(define (identifier-add-prefix identifier prefix)
  (datum->syntax identifier
                 (string->symbol (string-append prefix
                                                (symbol->string (syntax->datum identifier)))))
```

I convert a syntax object (assumed to be an identifier) into a datum, convert that symbol into a string, make a new string with the prefix prepended, convert that string into a symbol, and then finally turn that symbol into an identifier in the same syntactic environment as `identifier`.

This works, but it seems roundabout and messy. Is there a cleaner or more idiomatic way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it might not be a hygienic macro, i suppose you could use define-syntax like this (in chicken scheme).
For chicken scheme the documentation for macros is [here](http://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/Macros). Also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15997947/error-during-expansion-of-macro-in-chicken-scheme) sheds some light on chicken scheme macros. Finally i don't know if this would be an idiomatic way to approach the problem.

```
(use format)
(use srfi-13)

(define-syntax recgen
  (lambda (expr inject compare)
    `(define (,(string->symbol (string-append "make-" (cadr expr))) ) (format #t "called"))))

#> (recgen "bar")
#> (make-bar)
called
```

The single define above could be changed to a (begin ... ) that defines getters/setters or other ways to interact with the record.